# Embedding Python in a C++ program, how to deal with the GIL

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, gil

At work, we start an embedded Python interpreter from within a C++ program in firmware. The following program shows the essence of how the interpreter is run. In reality this starts a large program, but in this example a short command that illustrates the problem we ran into is shown.

```cpp
#include <Python.h>                                                                                                                                                                                        
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                                                                                                                                        
#include <string>                                                                                                                                                                                          

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){                                                                                                                                                                          
    Py_Initialize();                                                                                                                                                                                         
    PyEval_InitThreads();                                                                                                                                                                                    
    PyThreadState* mainState_ = PyEval_SaveThread();                                                                                                                                                         

    PyEval_AcquireLock();                                                                                                                                                                                    
    PyThreadState* initialState_ = Py_NewInterpreter();                                                                                                                                                      
    assert (initialState_!= 0);                                                                                                                                                                              
    PyThreadState* state_ = PyEval_SaveThread();                                                                                                                                                             

    int result;                                                                                                                                                                                              
    PyEval_RestoreThread(state_);                                                                                                                                                                            
    std::string command = 
        "import numpy as np; a=np.array([2,3]); b=np.array([2,0]); print(a/b)";                                                                                                            
    result = PyRun_SimpleString (command.c_str());                                                                                                                                                           
    state_ = PyEval_SaveThread();                                                                                                                                                                            

    return result;                                                                                                                                                                                           
}
```

This can be compiled using

`g++ main.cpp -o main $(python2.7-config --cflags --ldflags)`

When executing, this hangs the process. What seems to happen is that some Python libraries with threading support (NumPy, OpenCV), when trying to release and reacquire the GIL, end up deadlocked. In this example we force a division by zero in NumPy, which executes some NumPy-specific exception handling code which involves the GIL, and which causes a deadlock. Changing this to

```cpp
#include <Python.h>                                                                                                                                                                                        
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                                                                                                                                        
#include <string>                                                                                                                                                                                          

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){                                                                                                                                                                          

    Py_Initialize();                                                                                                                                                                                         

    int result;                                                                                                                                                                                              
    std::string command = 
        "import numpy as np; a=np.array([2,3]); b=np.array([2,0]); print(a/b)";                                                                                                            
    result = PyRun_SimpleString (command.c_str());                                                                                                                                                           

    return result;                                                                                                                                                                                           
}
```

it seemingly executes without any problem.

The real C++ program is multithreaded, and the Python executed from it is a very large program. The actual alternative program (i.e. the second example) would, rather than acquiring the GIL before executing Python (as in the first example), acquire a generic lock (mutex, semaphore) to avoid concurrent access.

I am not sure what was the reason to embed the interpreter in this way. Might this change in how the Python interpreter is called be unsafe or break things, like allowing multiple threads to concurrently access resources that should be protected, or can this change be safely made?

The person that implemented this is not around anymore, so I cannot ask him.

The version of Python we're using is 2.7.15, and versions of NumPy in which this happens are 1.8.2, 1.15.2, 1.16.5, and the g++ version is 7.4.0.

Comment: Why are you making a **sub**interpreter?

Comment: @DavisHerring I don't know, this is the code how we found it. AFAIK we only need a single python interpreter. Are you saying that in the first snippet we end up with two interpreter instances?

Comment: Sort of: subinterpreters are not quite complete interpreters (hence the name).  They’re also voodoo and don’t play well with certain uses of threading.  I’d start by stripping it out and seeing if that fixed anything.

Comment: @DavisHerring would you say the second snippet is like the first one, but with the subinterpreter stripped out, or not quite?

Comment: It also has all the GIL handling stripped.  The save/restore around the declaration of `result` was pointless, and you don’t need as much without the subinterpreter, but removing **all** of it could be bad if (in your real code) you expect other threads to execute Python code after this one finishes doing so.